# D3 - create sets of features from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a geojson where some features have a line property. I want to create a circle for each feature with a line property and to have its cy attribute set according to which line it belongs to e.g value = "u1" set to 50, value = "u2" set to 100. This is what I have so far. I cant filter the content to achieve this!

```
d3.json("stations.json", function(error, stations) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);

  var vis = d3.select("#network").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

    vis.selectAll("circle")
        .data(stations.features)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("cy", ?? )
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return i * 100 + 30; })
        .attr("r", 10 )
        .text(function(d){ return d.properties.title;});

})
```

Geojson:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Warschauer Str",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "13"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.448721,
          52.505889
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Schlesisches Tor",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "12"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.442426,
          52.501255
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Gorlizter Bahnhof",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "11"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.425292,
          52.4987404
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Kottbuster Tor",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "10"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.417748,
          52.499047
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Prinzenstrasse",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "9"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.406531,
          52.498274
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Hallesches Tor",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "8"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.39176,
          52.497774
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Mockernbrucke",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "7"

      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.383256,
          52.498944
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Gleisdreieck",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "6"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.374293,
          52.499587
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Kurfurstenstr",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "5"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.362814,
          52.49981
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Nollendorfplatz",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "4"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.353825,
          52.499644
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Wittenbergplatz",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "3"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.342561,
          52.502109
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Kurfurstendamm",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.331419,
          52.503763
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Uhlandstrasse",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.326233,
          52.502742
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Ruhleben",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u2",
          "id": "1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.241902,
          52.525587
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Olympia-Stadion",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u2",
          "id": "2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.2505,
          52.517048
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "green",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "title": "u1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            13.448810577392578,
            52.50613909894946
          ],
          [
            13.442459106445312,
            52.50122797169364
          ],
          [
            13.425207138061523,
            52.499033460891084
          ],
          [
            13.406667709350586,
            52.49835418534738
          ],
          [
            13.383407592773438,
            52.49924246663935
          ],
          [
            13.374481201171875,
            52.499817227323945
          ],
          [
            13.362979888916016,
            52.50002622934633
          ],
          [
            13.354053497314453,
            52.499817227323945
          ],
          [
            13.342294692993164,
            52.502325186017565
          ],
          [
            13.331737518310547,
            52.50394483330318
          ],
          [
            13.326072692871094,
            52.50279541234477
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#ff0000",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "title": "u2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            13.24247360229492,
            52.52624809700062
          ],
          [
            13.250541687011719,
            52.517683311303244
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to rely on the line property to contain a numeric value, so I put extra in to cut this dependency.

I extracted all the line names into an array and used the ordinal position in the array to come up the cy attribute.

also, i used the array.prototype.filter() rather than d3.filter(), d3.filter() adds empty circle elements to the svg for the non-matched items.

```
  var stationsArr = stations.features.filter(function(d) {
        return d.properties.line;
    });
    var lines = stationsArr.map(function(x) {
        return x.properties.line;
    });
    var uniqueLines = unique(lines);

    function unique(arr) {
        var u = {},
            a = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i) {
            if (!u.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
                a.push(arr[i]);
                u[arr[i]] = 1;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    function getX(d) {
        return d.properties.id * 50;
    }

    function getY(d) {
        var line = d.properties.line;
        var i = uniqueLines.indexOf(line) + 1;
        return i * 150;
    }

    stationGroup.selectAll("circle")
        .data(stationsArr)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "station")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return getX(d);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return getY(d);
        })
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "green")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.properties.title;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

For the positioning,  I something rather straightforward would work (assuming only the first character will be non-numeric):

```
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return d.properties.line.substring(1) * 40; })
```

Of course this will throw an error when the code comes across an undefined line property. You can filter by using something like :

```
  .enter().append("circle")
    .filter(function(d) { return (d.properties.line);  })
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return d.properties.line.substring(1) * 40; })
```

Together, that gives something like (modifying your positioning schema a little on the x axis to allow for the small snippet view):

```js
var stations = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Warschauer Str",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "13"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.448721,
          52.505889
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Schlesisches Tor",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "12"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.442426,
          52.501255
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Gorlizter Bahnhof",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "11"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.425292,
          52.4987404
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Kottbuster Tor",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "10"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.417748,
          52.499047
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Prinzenstrasse",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "9"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.406531,
          52.498274
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Hallesches Tor",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "8"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.39176,
          52.497774
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Mockernbrucke",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
        "id": "7"

      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.383256,
          52.498944
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Gleisdreieck",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "6"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.374293,
          52.499587
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Kurfurstenstr",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "5"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.362814,
          52.49981
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Nollendorfplatz",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "4"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.353825,
          52.499644
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Wittenbergplatz",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "3"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.342561,
          52.502109
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Kurfurstendamm",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.331419,
          52.503763
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Uhlandstrasse",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u1",
          "id": "1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.326233,
          52.502742
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Ruhleben",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u2",
          "id": "1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.241902,
          52.525587
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Olympia-Stadion",
        "popupContent": "x",
        "line": "u2",
          "id": "2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.2505,
          52.517048
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "green",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "title": "u1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            13.448810577392578,
            52.50613909894946
          ],
          [
            13.442459106445312,
            52.50122797169364
          ],
          [
            13.425207138061523,
            52.499033460891084
          ],
          [
            13.406667709350586,
            52.49835418534738
          ],
          [
            13.383407592773438,
            52.49924246663935
          ],
          [
            13.374481201171875,
            52.499817227323945
          ],
          [
            13.362979888916016,
            52.50002622934633
          ],
          [
            13.354053497314453,
            52.499817227323945
          ],
          [
            13.342294692993164,
            52.502325186017565
          ],
          [
            13.331737518310547,
            52.50394483330318
          ],
          [
            13.326072692871094,
            52.50279541234477
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stroke": "#ff0000",
        "stroke-width": 2,
        "stroke-opacity": 1,
        "title": "u2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            13.24247360229492,
            52.52624809700062
          ],
          [
            13.250541687011719,
            52.517683311303244
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

  var w = 500,
  h = 300;


  var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

    vis.selectAll("circle")
        .data(stations.features)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .filter(function(d) { return (d.properties.line);  })
        .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return d.properties.line.substring(1) * 40; })
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return i * 10 + 30; })
        .attr("r", 10 )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

If you are hoping to have two positioning schemes for where d.properties.line is defined and undefined, you could use an inline function with an if statement to switch between the two types.

Comment: you pushed me in the right direction andrew! i used the array.prototype.filter() rather than d3.filter(), d3.filter() adds empty circle elements to the svg for the non-matched items. see my full answer. thanks